# Split Objects in an Array

Tags: c#

so i am having a little issue at the moment. I read the html code of a website and store it in an array, so with every new line a new array index is filled.

```
line1 text // random stuff
line2 text // random stuff
line3 text // random stuff
line4 text // random stuff
```

this could be a example how the array looks after reading from the webpage. Now i want to split every object in that array after " // " so the array looks like that after:

```
line1 text
line2 text
line3 text
line4 text
```

Anyone has an idea, because i am struggeling on this. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It could work like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
{
    array[i] = array[i].Split('/')[0].Trim();
}
```

See [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/82aDAz) fiddle for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Using Split:

```
string[] arr = new string[]
{
    "line1 text // random stuff",
    "line2 text // random stuff",
    "line3 text // random stuff",
    "line4 text // random stuff",
    "line5 text // random stuff"
};

arr = arr.Select(x => x.Split('/')[0].Trim()).ToArray();
```